# Paypal PHP Curl returns nothing

Tags: php, curl, paypal

After succesfully testing my payment request on localhost with live credentials, I moved the application online.

On the live server however, the curl request gives me back nothing, not even an error message. It's the exact same request that works perfectly on localhost.

```
$url = 'curl -s --insecure -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: '.$userId.'" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: '.$password.'" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: '.$signature.'" -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: '.$applicationId.'" https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay -d "{\"actionType\":\"PAY\", \"currencyCode\":\"'.$currency.'\", \"receiverList\":{\"receiver\":[{\"amount\":\"'.$amount.'\",\"email\":\"'.$receiverEmail.'\"}]}, \"returnUrl\":\"'.$successUrl.'\", \"cancelUrl\":\"'.$failUrl.'\", \"requestEnvelope\":{\"errorLanguage\":\"en_US\", \"detailLevel\":\"ReturnAll\"}}';
$result = json_decode(exec($url));
```

Now that's the PHP. I tried to run the curl request in command line. On localhost I immediately get a correct return. On the live server, I first get a ">" sign, if I then paste the command again and enter, it gives me some output.

```
{"responseEnvelope":{"timestamp":"2013-07-05T13:16:26.305-07:00","ack":"Failure","correlationId":"2b8ab6998078e","build":"6520082"},"error":[{"errorId":"580001","domain":"PLATFORM","subdomain":"Application","severity":"Error","category":"Application","message":"Invalid request: {0}"}]}
```

The weird thing is that this works on localhost but not on the live server, so I figure it must be some difference in PHP, curl or server setting... but I really don't have a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the output of echo $url ?

Why are you running curl via exec? Why not use mod_curl ?

For example...

```
 $API_Endpoint = "";
    if ($sandbox) {
      $API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments";
    }
    else{
      $API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments";
  }

  $API_Endpoint .= "/" . $methodName;

  //setting the curl parameters.
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

  // Set the HTTP Headers
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array(
  'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV',
  'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV',
  'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: '. $API_UserName,
  'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: '. $API_Password,
  'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: '. $API_Signature,
  'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: '. $API_AppID
  ));

  // RequestEnvelope fields
  $detail_level = urlencode("ReturnAll"); // See DetailLevelCode in the WSDL for valid enumerations
  $error_language = urlencode("en_US"); // This should be the standard RFC 3066 language identification tag, e.g., en_US

  // NVPRequest for submitting to server
  $nvp_req = "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=$error_language&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=$detail_level";
  $nvp_req .= "&$nvp_str";

  //setting the nvp_req as POST FIELD to curl
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_req);

  //getting response from server
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
```